# How do I connect to Docker Postgres Container from an Outside CLI?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I have my Postgres container running, built from this docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        volumes:
            - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=db
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password.
```

It spins up fine & my other dockerized servers can connect to it. But, if I open up a CLI from outside the docker instance & try to connect with

```
psql postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/db
```

Or try to add a database connection in PyCharm, I get

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  database "db" does not exist
```

as a response. What do I need to do to allow outside calls to the containerized database? I've tried adding "expose:5432" to the docker compose, but that didnt help.

Comment: Looks like the problem is related to the way you are trying to connect, maybe your database name isn't `db` try to connect and list the databases and change the connection string accordingly. maybe try `postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432`
`

Comment: I have pgadmin running locally too, which is on 5432. would that interfere with it? I dont know how to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

answered my own question here - by stopping PgAdmin from running, which I guess was blocking the 5432 port, the containerized postgres service could be accessed by the CLI & PyCharm